# How to fill the input box with json object key and value in separate text box in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a data in header column which is in json format like {"API-KEY":"763754jkdsnfjk","ACTION":"HGHG"}. I want to get the key of json object in one text box and value in another textbox using foreach loop in codeigniter. I tried this method but it is not coming. can any one please help me how to achieve this.

```html
<?
 $arr=explode(',',$load_options['header']);
 $opt_count=count($arr);
?>

<div class="controls" id="profs"> 
 <form class="input-append" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>payment_gateway/update_asset_options">
  <input type="hidden" name="rowVal" id="rowVal" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="row_count" id="row_count" value="<?=$opt_count?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pre_count" id="pre_count" value="<?=$opt_count?>" />
  <? 
   //print_r($arr);die;
   $i=0;
   foreach($arr as $key => $val)
   {
    $display_name=$key;
    $db_val=$val; 
    if($i>0)
    {
     $remClass="removeclass".$i;
    }
    else
    {
     $remClass="";
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row <?=$remClass?>" >
     <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control display_name" id="display_name<?=$i?>" name="display_name<?=$i?>" value="<?=$display_name?>" placeholder="Display Name" required >
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
      <div class="form-group ">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="db_value<?=$i?>" name="db_value<?=$i?>" value="<?=$db_val?>" placeholder="Value" required />
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="def_value<?=$i?>" name="def_value<?=$i?>" value=""  />
      </div>
     </div>
     <?   
      if($i>0)
      {?>
       <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn " type="button"  onclick="remove_fields(<?=$i?>);" title="Remove Rows"> <i class="fa fa-minus text-danger" ></i> </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      <? }
      echo "</div>";
      $i++; 
   } 
  ?>
        <div id="education_fields"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
     <a href="javascript:;" class="btn " type="button"  onclick="add_fields();"title="Add Rows"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
  <center>
   <button class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" >Save</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </center>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: which fields in the form are you hoping to add the content to? `display_nameX` and `def_valueX`? Can you add a larger sample of source data?

Comment: In the display_nameX text box i want to fill the key and in the def_valueX i want to fill the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 
`$arr=explode(',',$load_options['header']);`

Into this 
`$arr = json_decode($load_options['header'],true);`